# iOS displaying invisible Unicode characters as dotted box containing “mvs”

Tags: html, ios, unicode

I’m trying to use invisible Unicode characters to watermark text to give a clue to its origin when someone copy/pastes it to somewhere else.

It’s working great on desktop, but it’s been pointed out that on iOS it’s  displaying a weird “mvs” character that I’ve never seen before (and can’t seem to find any reference to in my searches).

[An example is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384714/899365) using MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR (U+180E) and ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B). I’ve copy/pasted them here too via iOS but not sure what will happen on desktop:

```
Yes, there is a X11 way to do this:​​​᠎᠎​᠎​​᠎​​​​​​᠎᠎᠎​᠎​​᠎​​​​

Scroll down and log the OS.
Re-go to your tools/Gcc Terminal/}Tools Configuration.
Include the x11 usr library9
```

The characters at the end of the line are invisible on desktop but on iOS you see this:

[image: iOS screenshot]

What is this “mvs” in a box character? Is this something specific to the invisible character(s) I selected? Or is iOS doing something funky to invisible Unicode?

Comment: MVS may stand for “Mongolian vowel separator” — I’m going to try something else and see if that works better.

Comment: "*I’m trying to use invisible Unicode characters to watermark text to give a clue to its origin when someone copy/pastes it to somewhere else*" - you really should not be doing that in the first place. Text is text, leave it alone. The receiver shouldn't care where it comes from, and is not guaranteed to support the characters you are trying to use for the watermark.

Comment: In any case, the MVS appears the way it does because you are not using it correctly to begin with, per the Unicode spec: "*U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR is a **word-internal thin whitespace that may occur only before the word-final vowels U+1820 MONGOLIAN LETTER A and U+1821 MONGOLIAN LETTER E**. It determines the specific form of the character preceding it, selects a special variant shape of these vowels, and produces a small gap within the word..."*"  In other words, it can't be used as a standalone watermark character in your text.  So iOS is displaying a default glyph for that character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR` is not invisible on iOS. I've switched to 0 being represented by `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` (`U+200B`) and 1 being represented by `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` (`U+200C`).

The following snippet should let you convert an arbitrary `ASCII` string to this encoding:

```
var encodeInvisibleBinary = function(str) {
    var digits = [
        '&#x200b;',  // ZERO WIDTH SPACE
        '&#x200c;'   // ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
    ];

    var binary = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++) {
        binary = binary.concat(str[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2).split(''));
    }
    binary = _.map(binary, function(c) {
        return digits[c];
    });
    return binary.join('');
};

encodeInvisibleBinary('robo');
// outputs: &#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;
```

And the reverse (decoding back to ASCII):

```
var decodeInvisibleBinary = function(str) {
    var binaryString = '';
    var parts = str.split('&#x200');
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
        if(parts[i] == 'b;') binaryString += '0';
        if(parts[i] == 'c;') binaryString += '1';
    }
    var binaryChars = binaryString.split(/([01]{7})/);
    var ret = '';
    for(i=0; i<binaryChars.length; i++) {
        ret += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(binaryChars[i], 2));
    }
    return ret;
};

decodeInvisibleBinary('&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;');
// outputs: robo
```